# How to speed up reading in input in Java

Tags: java, dijkstra

I am attempting to read in info from files to implement Dijkstra's algorithm. I believe that the double for loop is causing this to drastically slow down, is there anyway around this?

```
Edge[] edge = new Edge[127807];
                int indexEdge = 0; 
                String line2 = "";
                BufferedReader fileReader2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Road.txt"));
                String valueString = null;
                String vertex1IDName = null;
                String vertex2IDName = null;
                String extra = null;
                float value = 0;
                int vertex1ID = 0;
                int vertex2ID = 0;
                //Read the file line by line
                while ((line2 = fileReader2.readLine()) != null) 
                {
                    //Get all tokens available in line
                    String[] tokens2 = line2.split(DELIMITER);
                    for(String token1 : tokens2)
                    {
                        vertex1IDName = tokens2[0];
                        vertex2IDName = tokens2[1];
                        valueString = tokens2[2];
                        if(tokens2.length - 1 == 3) {
                            extra = tokens2[tokens2.length - 1];
                        }
                        else {
                            extra = "";
                        }
                        vertex1ID = Integer.parseInt(vertex1IDName);
                        vertex2ID = Integer.parseInt(vertex2IDName);
                        value = Float.parseFloat(valueString);

                    }
                    System.out.println("value: "+ value + " vertex1ID:"+ vertex1ID +" vertex2ID:"+ vertex2ID+ " extra:" + extra);
                    //if vertex 1 name or vertex 2 name in vertex.getID()
                    for(int i = 0; i< indexVertex; i++) {
                        for(int j = 0; j< indexVertex; j++) {
                            if(vertex1ID == vertex[i].getID() && vertex2ID == vertex[j].getID()) {
                                vertex[i].addNeighbour(edge[indexEdge] = new Edge(value,vertex[i],vertex[j],extra));
                                indexEdge++;
                            }   
                        }
                    }            
                }
```

Comment: 1. Don't use `System.out.println` and `+` of strings (to improve runtime, but this won't overcome the 'algorithmical flavors')

Comment: You'd be well-served by building an index of vertices, so you can look them up by id. But a trivial speedup would come from putting the `if(vertex1ID == vertex[i].getID())` check outside the j loop, since there is no point in iterating the inner loop if i doesn't match.

Comment: 2. (Of course) **Don't** iterate `V x V` for *each* edge!

Comment: In the 'for(String token1 : tokens2)' loop, you never use 'token1'.  So, you do the same calculations once for every token

Comment: ...1. Read all edges (into appropriate structure ..e.g. list/array/set ...)2.(finally) close the file. 3. ...then you can process `VxV` (if you still need to)

Comment: You believe it is slowing you down why? Compared to what?

Comment: Thanks, I moved the `if(vertex1ID == vertex[i].getID())` check outside the j loop, and it sped it up considerably. I'm not sure about the 'token' bit or building an index of vertices.

Comment: Did you follow @DavidZimmerman ‘s suggestion to get rid of the “ for(String token1 : tokens2)”, since nothing inside that loop uses token1 ?

Comment: I did get rid of the  `for(String token1 : tokens2)`  but it didn't seem o have any noticeable speed affects. I'm thinking of changing the `Edge[] edge = new Edge[127807];` to a different data structure, maybe a Hash Set since I'm storing Vector Objects, any ideas about this?